# How to make HTTP Get request in Github for example Get Issues using R?

Tags: r, git, github, github-api

So I want to gather some information about an Institute where students upload projects and stuff in Github.

So I want to gather all that an analyse it. But in order to do that I have to request it from git hub. I want to do that using **R**. Or secondary using **Python**.

But i dont quite understand how could I use that in R as a get Request.

So if anyone could show me an example I would appreciate that.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests is a HTTP library for python that is very robust and easy to use. JSON and XML responses can be parsed easily.

Use it as below

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Use Github credentials`'user'` and `'pass'` for authentication.

To get a list of reporsitories by a user or oranisation you can use Github's REST APIs.
Github has a REST API documentation. An HTTP GET request as below can fetch repositories for the specified org.

```
GET /orgs/:org/repos
```

find it here https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories